# tableView not setting automatic row height

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, row-height

In my project, I have a static tableView with 3 sections. The cell in the second section holds a label that is filled dynamically and therefore has a dynamic height. The cell should adjust its height to the label's height. Here's what I tried, without success:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      return 44
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
      return 80
    } else {
      return 50
    }
}
```

The heights of all sections are set properly except the automatic dimensions. Any help?

Comment: More information would be useful - did you set all the constraints for your cell?  Did you set the label properly (ie numberOfLines = 0, lineBreakMode)?

Comment: I set the constraints of the label to left 10, top 10 and right 10. The label has 0 lines and the default lineBreakMode (Truncate Tail). Anything to change here?

Comment: Yeah you want lineBreakMode to be word wrap!  The 0 lines is correct, you need that to have a multiline label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

then write this `table view` method

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

also make sure you have used the `auto layout` properly.
and you have set the `number of lines for lable = 0`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, maybe something with the autoLayout? I only set constraints for the label within the cell (left 10, top 10, right 10) and set the lines to be 0.

Comment: plz give bottom constraints also

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Don't  hesitate to rate up

Answer (score 0):

You also need to provide an estimated row height. You can do that by using the `estimatedRowHeight` property of your `UITableView`, or implementing the corresponding delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return XXXXX // Provide your estimation here, or pass UITableViewAutomaticDimension (not the best for performances)
}
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html